# How to create a class library using serilog as a referenced package?

Tags: c#, serilog

I have a solution containing multiple .NET Core API and windows service projects. How can I integrate Serilog in such a way that I will not be required to make changes at several different places for adding a column or changing some property?

I'm thinking of adding Serilog in a common library and use that custom library in all other projects so the overhead of installing serilog and other enrichers in each application will be removed and each application doesn't need to take care of logging logs it will be done by custom library.
Below are the points that I need to cover.

1. How to invoke starting point of the serilog when it is in the library.
2. Once the instance is created from the application through library, the instance should be accessible throughout the application like in windows service.
3. How to pass application configuration(serilog) details(appSettings.json) at run time(1st time) to the custom library using dependency injection.

Below is the code, but it's not working and it's not written correctly, I need to have a dependency injection that can pass configuration to the library once the application starts.

Custom library code

```
 public class MySerilog
    {
        private ILogger logger;
        public MySerilog(IConfiguration config)
        {
            logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
         .ReadFrom.Configuration(config).CreateLogger();
         
        }

        public void Information(string message)
        {
            logger.Information(message);
        }   
    }
```

In Controller.

```
public class LogServiceController : Controller
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
       {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private ILogManager logManager;
       // private readonly ILogger<LogServiceController> _logger;
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public LogServiceController()
        {
            // _logger = logger;
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
              .Build();
            logManager = new LogManager(null);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
          // logManager.Information("WeatherForecastControllerTesting");
            // _logger.LogInformation("WeatherForecast");
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Error"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [

      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "pathFormat": "C:\\Users\\logs.txt",
          //"outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff}|{TenantName}|{RequestId}|{SourceContext}|{Level:u3}|{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Mysterious228 if you found a way how to implement custom library, can you share your solution because I have same problem